# Bootstrap-table : text in Chinese

Tags: translation, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap table in one of my web page.
Bootstrap table : [link](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)

I have a little and funny problem :
[image: screenshot]

As you can see boostrap table texts are in chinese.
How to change the language ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A mistake with cdn.

In bootstrap-table web site in [Getting started](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/) the CDN link is :

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Locales -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.6.0/locale/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>
```

It's the chinese CDN.

Others CDN are here : [list of CDN](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-table)

Comment: could you clarify your own answer a little bit... are you saying that because you used someone else's customized version of bootstrap as your CDN, it was set to use chinese as teh default?

Comment: the CDN in "Getting Started" is the chinese cdn.

Answer (score 0):

Add these below js files and css file.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/locale/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also set the locale in bootstrap-table to 'en-US' e.g

```
      height: 550,
      locale: 'en-US',
```

where $table is the reference to the id of your bootstrapTable